# Implementation of ITargetDefinition

Tags: eclipse

I want to use to interface ITargetDefinition.class in my code. Now I am wondering where the actual source file of the interface can be found? When I press F3 I get the message

*The source attachment does not contain the source for the file ITargetDefinition.class. You can change the source attachement by clicking Change Attached Sources below.*

The documentation of the interface can be found here: [ibm.com/docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rsar/9.5?topic=SS5JSH_9.5.0/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/api/org/eclipse/pde/core/target/class-use/ITargetDefinition.html). Where can I find/ download the actual implementation of this interface? I have tried to download "Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources" and "Eclipse Project SDK" from "https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/latest"... but I can still not find the source.

Comment: You should just have to install Eclipse Project SDK in your current Eclipse and the source of the interface should be found automatically. The actually implementation is `org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinition` which should also be included in that install. If you are using a target platform that needs to include the SDK rather than the main Eclipse.

Comment: You may also want to set the "include all plug-ins from target in Java workspace scope" option in the "Plug-in Development" page of the Preferences to help with searching.

Comment: You [already asked that, but then deleted the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72934985/6505250). Which IDE do you use exactly (obviously, it's not the [Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-06/r/eclipse-ide-eclipse-committers))?

Comment: I use Eclipse 4.22.0. I don't know how to search for files... I tried Eclipse > Search > Search..., but without success. Thanks greg for the name of the actual implementation "org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinition", when I Google it, I find the file. However, I have no idea how to search for files in a systematic way? How could I have known about the "internal" in the paths... this is not there in the official documentation of the interface...

Comment: I found the implementation by opening the ITargetDefinition interface in Eclipse and using the Eclipse search to find classes that implemented the interface (there is only the one). Details about how things like this are implemented is not part of the Eclipse API and are not documented, they may be different in each release.

Comment: As already mentioned it would be easiest to use the Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers package as this already has all the source plug-ins included.